# How to select all instances of family in Revit?

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I am creating a plugin for Revit 2019 and want to select all the instances of specific family and type through API. "ElementClassFilter" is available in Revit sdk to filter the elements but I want to display all instances of same type in blue lines. I have filtered the specific type through "ElementClassFilter" but looking for how to select them in revit through API.

The following code is for filtering elements of specific family and type.

```
ElementClassFilter filter = new ElementClassFilter(typeof(FamilyInstance));
FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(document);
collector.WherePasses(filter);
var query = from element in collector where element.Name == "Single-Standard" select element;

List<FamilyInstance> familyInstances = query.Cast<FamilyInstance>().ToList<FamilyInstance>();
```

But I want to show all instances of same family and type in the following image

["Window: Single-Standard" image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3szOr.png)

Comment: as I understand, you want to have the selection in the revit interface, once you press your plugin button? like an automatic selection plugin?

Comment: Yes, I want selection in revit interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIApplication UIapp = commandData.Application;
UIDocument UIdoc = UIapp.ActiveUIDocument;
Document doc = UIdoc.Document;

FilteredElementCollector elementCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);
elementCollector.OfClass(typeof(FamilyInstance));

Selection sel = UIdoc.Selection;
sel.SetElementIds(elementCollector.ToList().Select(o => o.Id).ToList()); //User selection
```

This is a simple example to how to set the user selection.
For mor info of revit Selection class you can visit this [link](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2019/31b73d46-7d67-5dbb-4dad-80aa597c9afc.htm).